# How can I remove a parenthesis that begins with a specific string using python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a cleanup script to remove a string that gets added to the description of the objects/entities/items that are migrated.

IE:

A field called "Asset" has the following description "Select the asset you will be using (you can select multiple assets)". Post migration, the asset will look like "Select the asset you will be using (you can select multiple assets) (Migrated on 17 May 2023 20:53 UTC)"

The script will go through the different objects cleaning their description by removing the added string and restoring it to the original value:

From this - "Select the asset you will be using (you can select multiple assets) (Migrated on 17 May 2023 20:53 UTC)"

To this - "Select the asset you will be using (you can select multiple assets)"

I was hoping to use something like this:

```
import re

description = description = "Select the asset you will be using (you can select multiple assets) (Migrated on "

result = re.sub("", "", description)
result2 = result.split('(')
if result2[1].startswith('Migrated on'):
    description = result2[0]

print(description)
```

But that would remove ALL text that are between parenthesis so, I tried to use the below approach but, I think it can be way better than this.

```
description = "Select the asset you will be using (you can select multiple assets) (Migrated on "
try:
     description.index(mig)
except ValueError:
     print("Not found!")
else:
     position = description.index(mig)
     description = description[:position]
print(description)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
import re

description = "Select the asset you will be using (you can select multiple assets) (Migrated on 17 May 2023 20:53 UTC)"
cleaned = re.sub(r'\(Migrated on .*\)$', '', description).strip()

print(cleaned)
```

**Output**

```
Select the asset you will be using (you can select multiple assets)
```

Comment: Can you add a short description for that regular expression?

Comment: @doneforaiur `\(Migrated on .*\)$` matches the text "Migrated on" followed by any characters, enclosed within parentheses, and situated at the end of the string. The empty string `''`, indicates that the matched pattern should be replaced with nothing, effectively removing it. And ofc `strip()` to remove any leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: I meant adding description in the original answer for better reference. :')